# Take the same subset from many matrices of the same size in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, subset

Say I have many matrices `a,b,c,d...z`

They are all the same dimension,

```
>> size(a)

ans =

   M   N
```

Now, I want to get (assuming `mod(M,2)=0` and `mod(N,3)=0`)

```
a_new = a(1:2:end,1:3:end);
b_new = b(1:2:end,1:3:end);
.
.
.
z_new = z(1:2:end,1:3:end);
```

Is there a way to do this easily?

**Important note**: I want to do this to **all** the elements in the current workspace of the size `MxN`, so, if there is a way to filter all the current variables of `MxN` and take the subset that would suffice.

Comment: If all of your matrices have the same size, they should be generated *from the start* as elements of a 3-dimensional array of size `MxNx26` (or however many arrays you have. Then operations like this are trivial: `alphabet_new = alphabet(1:2:end, 1:3:end, :)`.

Comment: Yes, true. I am aware of that. But sometimes you inherit the workspace and you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dynamic variable names are **[a very, very, very, very bad idea](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval)**.

If you really need to do something consider using [cell arrays](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) or other alternatives linked in the tutorial above.

If you still want to do this, consider following snippet:

```
list = who;
for k=1:length(list)
    if ismatrix(eval(list{k})) && all(size(eval(list{k})) == [M, N])
        eval([list{k},'_new = ',list{k},'(1:2:end,1:3:end);']);
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's a terrible idea but once I have this defined I just need a workaround. So, in your example `[N,M] = [3,3]` , right?

Comment: Yep, forgot to change that.